# How to required false list of multipart files?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a pojo which contains the list of images.
While saving data I do not select any images to save, it returns me a type miss match error in controller.
I want to required false the images list which having multipart files.
what should i do ?

*****************************Error*****************************************
[http-nio-8087-exec-11] ERROR com.iconicus.error.restapp.RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler - 400 Status Code
org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 2 errors
Field error in object 'productform' on field 'imageses[0].productimage': rejected value []; codes [typeMismatch.productform.imageses[0].productimage,typeMismatch.productform.imageses.productimage,typeMismatch.imageses[0].productimage,typeMismatch.imageses.productimage,typeMismatch.productimage,typeMismatch.org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [productform.imageses[0].productimage,imageses[0].productimage]; arguments []; default message [imageses[0].productimage]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile] for property 'imageses[0].productimage'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile] for property 'productimage': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
Field error in object 'productform' on field 'imageses[1].productimage': rejected value []; codes [typeMismatch.productform.imageses[1].productimage,typeMismatch.productform.imageses.productimage,typeMismatch.imageses[1].productimage,typeMismatch.imageses.productimage,typeMismatch.productimage,typeMismatch.org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [productform.imageses[1].productimage,imageses[1].productimage]; arguments []; default message [imageses[1].productimage]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile] for property 'imageses[1].productimage'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile] for property 'productimage': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.iconicus.app.filter.FebnexFilter.doFilter(FebnexFilter.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.invokeWithWrappedRequest(DebugFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

*************************************Controller***************************

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/updateimages"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ApiResponse updateImages(@ModelAttribute("productform") Product productForm, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IOException {
    int responsedata = 0;
    try {
        productService.updateProductImages(productForm);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
    return new ApiResponse(HttpStatus.OK, "Product Updated", String.valueOf(productForm.getId()), true);
}
```

*********************************** Product (POJO) **********************

public class Product {

```
private String id;
private String productname;
private String displayname;
private String productprice;
private String category;
private String subcategory;
private String categoryname;
private String subcategoryname;
private String taxcategory;
private String productweight;
private String description;
private String productsortorder;
private String productsku;
private String productshippingweight;
private String fixshippinginindia;
private String fixshippingworldwide;
private String allowcod;
private String visible;
private String active;
private String allowpurchaseind;
private String allowpurchaseworldwide;
private String freeshippinginindia;
private String freeshippingworldwide;
private String shippingasperweigth;
private String[] tags;
private ProductSeo productSeo;
private ProductOption productOption;
private List<ProductOptionSet> optionSets;
private List<ProductImages> imageses;
private List<ProductGroupTag> groupTag;
private List<ProductSeoDetail> seodetails;
private List<NoteForm> noteForm;
```

}

****************************Product Image (POJO)************************

public class ProductImages {

```
private String id;
private String productid;
private MultipartFile productimage;
private String productimagename;
private String imagetitle;
private String imagedescription;
private String imageseotitle;
private String imageseokeyword;
private String imageseodescription;
private String fileaction;
```

}

Comment: Please post your controller.

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = {"/updateimages"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ApiResponse updateImages(@ModelAttribute("productform") Product productForm, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IOException {
        int responsedata = 0;
        try {
            productService.updateProductImages(productForm);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }

Comment: public class Product {
    private String id;
    private String taxcategory;
    private String freeshippingworldwide;
    private String shippingasperweigth;
    private String[] tags;
    private ProductSeo productSeo;
    private ProductOption productOption;
    private List<ProductOptionSet> optionSets;
    private List<ProductImages> imageses;
    private List<ProductGroupTag> groupTag;
    private List<ProductSeoDetail> seodetails;
    private List<NoteForm> noteForm;

Comment: public class ProductImages {

    private String id;
    private String productid;
    private MultipartFile productimage;
    private String productimagename;
    private String imagetitle;

Answer (score 0):

Check you have enabled MultipartResolver or not. You can use CommonsMultipartResolver to handle the file upload. Then below snippet can do needful:

```
public String fileHandleController(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute Pojo pojo) {
    //check your request is multipart
    String contentType = request.getContentType();
    if(contentType != null && contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") > -1) {
        MultipartFile multipartFile = pojo.getFile();
        if(multipartFile.getSize() > 0){
            //to do
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please chect it above

Comment: Please give me solution